# TikZ package help with drawing something!

Tags: fonts

I am new around here. I need your help with something in LaTeX. I am doing something, but I don't know how to do this. I will post picture, because I need to write the code for this just from this picture. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is I really dont even know how to start this. We didn't even do a sample thats somekind close to this one. That is why am I asking here, I can't find any solution for this. I am sorry for my "off-topic" or whatever this is, I just don't know what to do. I am not asking this just for myself, but for a lot of students that need this. I wrote everything in Latex but this. Sorry once again, if anyone knows how to help me to draw lines like this, I would appreaciate it.

Comment: In principle it is not that hard to do it with [`pgfplots`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). Because the manual is quite large because of all the possibilities and examples, maybe this [TUG article](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-1/tb97wright-pgfplots.pdf) of Joseph Wright is a good starting guide. Also you will find a lot of question regarding this package here on TeX.SX when you search for the tag "[[pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots)]".

Comment: If this is homework, have you tried asking your instructor? If nobody knows how to even start, s/he really needs to know that!

Comment: @cfr the thing is we need to do this by ourselves, without any help. But samples they gave us for tikz picture and pgf are nothing like this.

Comment: @Safari8331 Then asking here is cheating. That is, based on what you've said, that would be my conclusion. Do you plan to acknowledge this question as a source when you submit your homework? If so, then that would obviously not be cheating, although it would presumably undermine your submission if you are meant to do it by yourself. Are you sure the assignment didn't expect you to do something radical such as, say, looking at the documentation?

Comment: @Safari8331 And I stand by what I said. If you've been asked to do something you have no idea how to do, the solution is not to ask other people to do it for you, but to discuss it with your instructor. Have you even tried this? Otherwise, if 50% of you turn in solutions, the students who don't get somebody else to do it for them will be penalised because your instructor will believe that it was reasonable to expect you to complete the exercise.

Comment: We dont have any literature what so ever for LaTeX. We use presentations that they gave us. Sorry for cheating, I am willing to learn about this, and I would do it from that example anyway, but I cant find solution to draw this. I looked at many manuals and other stuff, but nothing that could help me to get this right.

Anyway, if you really dont have anything else to say but to talk about penalties or something that will came with this question, even tho someone helps me with this, I will learn this, and try to figure out how and why. I did 99% of my assigment, and this is the last thing.

Comment: @cfr So I am cant say I am sorry for doing this, I came here to learn, not to give my assigment to others, this is just last piece of puzzle I need to do.

Comment: Well you could attribute this question in your homework. Then you will have learnt, your instructor will know that you needed additional help and there will be no suggestion at all of your doing anything wrong.

Comment: @cfr You should come to my class sometimes, I see you know a lot, so maybe you can help us get this with our instructor :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because at present it appears to be a directly-assigned piece of coursework.

Comment: You can delete it if you ask me @JosephWright

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the data so I made it up but you now know how to draw stuff. So you can read the manual to furnish it more. Search on this site and you'll get started pretty quickly. Search for the tag `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymax=10,ymin=-150,xmin=0,xmax=50,no marks,ylabel={$|H(f)|$ [dB]},xlabel={$f$ [Mhz]}]
\addplot+[domain=0.05:50] {20*log10((0.5/x))+rand};
\addplot+[domain=0.05:50] {20*log10((0.5/x^3))+rand};
\addplot+[domain=0.05:50] {20*log10((0.1/x^4))+rand};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also add the legend and maybe a commented line on how to use `\addplot table`. Then OP most probably has everything he needs for starting to modify it to his needs.